# img это inline-block или inline элемент?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, img

img является inline(встроенный, или строчным) или inline-block?

Comment: Спасибо. Можете написать это в ответ и я помечу как решение :)

Answer (score 3):

У `<img />` есть ширина и высота - поэтому `inline-block`. Так же на [w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp) пишут, что "большинство браузеров отображают `<img>` со стандартным значением `display:inline-block`"